# (Godot) how to create a 2d shadow with a sprite + blending mode?

Tags: shader, sprite, godot

I have a node 2d for my player object. It has a sprite child with the player sprite.
I want to redraw the same sprite but black + with some blending mode so that it affects the background.
Below is an example I made using Photoshop of what I want the shadow to look like. its using a softlight blending mode.
I have already looked into gdShaders but Im very new with that topic. Is there a resource where I can learn how I can accomplish this shadow effect with gdShader? I appreciate it thanks.
[image]

Comment: Write a **GLSL Shader**. You can learn how using the official Godot demos, one of which is “**2D Sprite Shaders**”.

Comment: Thank you! think i found it. This will probably help. https://godotengine.org/asset-library/asset/522

Comment: Yes, that’s it. The girl with the pink shadow can have a shadow made any color or alpha you wish.