# draw sprites to surface? ( I want to create a surface layer for shadows )

Tags: shader, sprite, shadow, godot

Im coming from game maker studio background and the engine would let you draw sprites onto surfaces. A way to achieve shadows was to add a script to instances that required shadows. the script would draw a sprite of itself with a little bit of an offset onto the shadow surface layer. With the surface ready, you can then paint the surface black + add some alpha.

Is there a way to achieve a similar effect in godot?

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D? Can you provide an example of the effect you want?

Comment: Wait, is this what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74909595/godot-how-to-create-a-2d-shadow-with-a-sprite-blending-mode You got a suggestion in comments, what happened with that?